# WinForms - Background is grey during runtime but not in the design window

Tags: winforms

During runtime the background is grey but I haven't made this the case in the design window or the Form's code.

[image: Forms design vs actual window]

I have no code in Form1's class that changes the colour of the form's background, however I believe the issue lies in the code in Program.cs:

```
namespace ImageTagger
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static Form1 form1 = new Form1();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            form1.IsMdiContainer = true;
            Application.Run(form1);
        }
    }
}
```

I can prove this isn't an issue with changing Form1's background colour because upon changing the background colour to blue in the design window, the background still turns grey but the labels are now blue.

[image: Blue in design, background still gray, labels blue]

Is this some issue with rendering?

Comment: Try removing `form1.IsMdiContainer = true;`

Answer (score 0):

As LarsTech commented, the solution was to simply remove `form1.IsMdiContainer = true;`